# Strange behavior - error happens but exception isn't thrown

Tags: c#

Here's what I have:

```
Debug.WriteLine("myMethod ok");
db.myTable.AddObject(new_item);
db.SaveChanges();
Debug.WriteLine("myMethod save changes");
```

And in the output window, I get:

```
"myMethod ok"
```

and nothing after that. So, AddObject and SaveChanges don;t throws exception because if they would, I would get that exception when I debug.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What happens when you debug, does it finish the execution or not?

Comment: What's the rest of the code?  Is this a console application, windows application, or something other?  How are you debugging - Visual Studio?  What happens if you put a breakpoint on the second `Debug.WriteLine` line?  You need to have a lot more information than you've provided.  I would bet that those methods *are* throwing an exception that your debugger isn't catching.

Comment: Strange, if you go to Debug -> Exceptions and then check the "Thrown" box for "Common Language Runtime Exception" Visual Studio should break on the majority of exceptions, this may give you a clue to what's happening.

Comment: @PaulieWaulie: it's also worth disabling "Just My Code" in the debugging options.

Comment: @DanPuzey, Always forget that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-reading your question, I realized it also could be a different issue. Perhaps `db.SaveChanges();` hangs forever, Put a break point in at the top of the function and step through.

---

The exception may be being caught by a higher level try-catch block that is calling your function.

You can follow what is happening by enabling "Catch Exceptions on Thrown" by going to the `Debug->Execptions...` dropdown menu and checking the `Thrown` box for Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

[image]

This will cause your code to break on the exception, even if it is inside a try-catch block.

If you do not see the box for "User-Unhanded" to check like the below picture

[image]

go to `Debug -> Options and Settings...` and be sure the box for "Enable Just My Code" is checked.

[image]

If it is not checked it will break on internal exceptions thrown by the .NET framework that do not represent problems, just control of flow logic that is implemented via exceptions in the framework (Most of the time it is a TimeOutExecption of some kind).

If the exception is still not being caught, try it again with "Just My Code" unchecked, just be aware of the possible "red-herring" exceptions the framework may throw.

Answer (score 0):

Check menu DEBUG - Exceptions and mark all Thrown checkboxes.
Maybe than you will receive the Exception.